# How can I run black formatting on a cookiecutter template?

Tags: python, pre-commit, cookiecutter, python-black

I am using pre-commit with `black` and `flake8` hooks.

I got this `error: cannot format` when trying to black-format the following code

```py
from {{cookiecutter.project_name}} import my_module
```

Is there anyway to indicate black, to skip/ignore cookiecutter-specific syntax?

Comment: I'd suggest running/testing the formatting *after* expansion -- linting template code can be tricky

Comment: It's just that I'm creating a scaffolding library. I need it to be flake8 compatible. It's a requirement. I think I'll do it by hand at the moment.

Comment: How about excluding the `{{cookiecutter.project_slug}}` directory altogether? That's what I did on [this](https://github.com/engineervix/cookiecutter-pyproject) project.